# . / instead of / in crontab

Tags: linux, shell, cron, suse

I'm having an error while trying to execute a sh in my crontab (or in the normal shell) .
I made an user Xuser, and in his home directory make a symbolic link to /opt/app
/opt/app with this -->  drwxrwxr--  Xuser test
In this folder I save serveral sh and jar.

Now in the crontab of this user or even in the shell if I tried to execute this:

```
./opt/app/bin/ind.sh
-bash: ./opt/app/bin/ind.sh: No such file or directory
```

The Sh file is

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

java -jar /opt/app/bin/ind.jar
```

If I put a space between  . / it works

```
. /opt/app/bin/ind.sh
: command not found
Error: Unable to access jarfile /opt/app/bin/ind.jar
```

( Access the SH but seems that the problem pass to the jar hahaha )

Someone notice the problem??

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference, when you put a space between the `.` and the `/` the `.` is no more part of the file path but is an alias of `source` and means "execute the content of this file in the current shell".

```
// execute in a subshell
./foo/bar/baz.sh

// execute in this shell
. ./foo/bar/baz.sh

// this is not the same file as previously, unless we are at the root (/)
. /foo/bar/baz.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, I make a test running without the source.
This gave me and error of bad interpreter. 
With VI I use :set fileformat=unix and save the file and now works fine....